# Android: How do I separate it into 2 class?

Tags: android

I read a tutorial online about drawing a Circle (1st part of tutorial):
[Introduction to 2D drawing in Android with example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/introduction-to-2d-drawing-in-android.html#.VvRp7PhJmHs)

I got it worked.  Now I want to separate them into 2 classes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(new SimpleView(this));

    }

}
```

**SimpleView.java**

```
public class SimpleView extends SurfaceView {

public SimpleView(Context context) {

    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int x = getWidth();
    int y = getHeight();
    int radius;
    radius = 100;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);

}

}
```

However, I wasn't able to get them work: it never draws anything.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: change `SurfaceView` to `View`

Comment: @ssh Why? `SurfaceView extends View`

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but drawing scenarios are different.

Comment: @ssh You could explain that in an answer if you think that is the solution.

Comment: oh it works after I change it to View, may I ask what's the difference?  If I want to keep SurfaceView, what should I do?

Comment: May be you can do that: setContentView(new SimpleView(this).getRootView());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a SurfaceView you can, all you need to do is to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` on the constructor so the class will look like this:

```
public class SimpleView extends SurfaceView {

    public SimpleView(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setWillNotDraw(false); //notice this method call IMPORTANT
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();
        int radius;
        radius = 100;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);


    }
}
```